# Why my code is not giving the desired output

Tags: python, list, loops, sorting, for-loop

```
l = [(2, 1), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 5)]
a = []
l1 = l
n = len(l)
for i in range(n):
    a.append(l[i][1])
b = sorted(a)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if (l1[j][1] == b[i]):
            l[i] = l1[j]
            break;

print(l)
```

I wrote this python code to rearrange the element of the input list in a way that element(tuple in the list is considered as element) are placed according to the ascending order of each tuples 1st index value;
for example

```
input = [(2, 1), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 5)]
```

output should be

```
l = [(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (2, 5)]
```

(see the 2nd element of each tuple is in ascending order 1,2,3,4,5) what is wrong with my code

Comment: Did you log `b` to see how it is sorted?

Comment: Note this can be achieved in one line: `a=sorted(l, key=lambda x:x[1])`.

Comment: i know this can be achieved in one line but i want to know whats wrong with this code this code seems correct to me ,also i have checked the list b it is sorted in ascending order successfully

Comment: @codersanchez Because you're not exactly making a copy with `l1=l`. Both variables refer to the same thing in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following assignment:

```
l1 = l
```

`l1` becomes a name that refers to the same list object as `l`, so when you modify `l` at index `i` with:

```
l[i] = l1[j]
```

you actually also modify `l1` at index `i`, so when `j` gets iterated to one of the past values of `i`, `l1[j]` would no longer have the value of the original element.

You can remedy this issue by creating a new list object for `l1` with values copied from `l` instead:

```
l1 = l.copy()
```

Comment: bro thank you so much it works now

Comment: @codersanchez You should upvote and accept the answer instead of commenting.

Comment: i tried but it seems i can't upvote as i don't have enough reputaion

Comment: @codersanchez You can accept an answer by clicking on the grey check mark next to an answer with no reputation required.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sorting the original list **l** correctly according to the ascending order of the second element of each tuple.
I have modified your code and it works.

```
l = [(2, 1), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 5)]
sorted_l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(sorted_l)
```

[image: Output]